# Suggestion for "home" tab

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to propose a home tab to sit long with questions, tags, users, badges and unanswered. It should list for the specific user you are logged in as all the questions with favourite tags. That way if you are following several tags, you can see all the questions tagged accordingly and answer them instead of clicking through each one to see any answered/unanswered questions.

Comment: If I remember correctly, right now nothing is done on the server to filter the questions. It's simply javascript that paints them when they appear. I doubt this would be implemented.

Comment: Putting `intags:mine` in the search field should work, no need for a tab.